# PostgreSQL doesn't work in ubuntu 20.04 Django Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04

My `docker-compose` works fine and runs on `Windows 10` but when i tried to run it from `ubuntu 20.04` i get the `DB` errors.

My django `settings.py` file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': env('SQL_ENGINE'),
        'NAME': env('SQL_DATABASE'),
        'USER': env('SQL_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env('SQL_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': env('SQL_HOST'),
        'PORT': env('SQL_PORT'),
    }
}
```

my `.env` file:

```
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=my_db
SQL_USER=my_admin
SQL_PASSWORD=my_api
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_PORT=5432
```

My 'docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  web:
    build: ./pets
    command: gunicorn pets.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - .env
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - "1337:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.10.0-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apk update
RUN apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY .. $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/staticfiles
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/mediafiles
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

First error i got:

```
FATAL: role "my_admin" does not exist
```

When i change the `SQL_USER` to `postgres` i've got the next error:

```
FATAL: database "my_db" does not exist
```

After this i change the `SQL_DATABASE` to `postgres`, but still i've got:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist"
```

What's wrong? Why it doesn't work on ubuntu 20.04, but perfectly works on windows 10?

Comment: It doesn't look like you set any of the `POSTGRES_*` environment variables to initialize the database.  See the [Docker Hub `postgres` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) for more details.

Comment: @DavidMaze hmm, for what reasons then can it work on windows?

Comment: Are you running "docker desktop" or something else?

Comment: @jjanes yes, docker desktop for start docker daemon in wsl2

Comment: Without the .pets directory, this cannot be reproduced/verified.

Comment: My best guess is that somehow you created your database correctly on Windows in the past, and now each time you start it just reuses that database.  Since you don't reinit the database, the brokenness of your current init config is not apparent.  If you were to purge all the volumes from Windows and rerun, it would probably be broken there as well.

Comment: @jjanes yes, i think it's true, because early i used not `SQL_...` env. variables but `POSTGRES_...`, so... :)